# Comparing two recordings of the same sound

Tags: audio, analytics

Okay, I'm searching for a way to compare two audio samples

which are recordings of the same sound

as heard from a fixed point when it is played in two different points of a room.

Could the acoustic effects be analyzed and compared?

.

Programming is not my area at all, but as a sound engineer I have huge interest in this.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts.
Rob

Answer (score 0):

If you also have the source material, you could deconvolve the recorded sound with the original and get the impulse response. From there you can calculate all kinds of acoustical parameters such as spaciousness and speech intelligibility. In general these acoustical parameters will vary from position to position.